# DXA development documents

Tags: dxa

I just start to look into DXA Java version for a prototype project. I have been doing some google search but I could not find anything for development guide. I could setup and deploy the war to Tomcat server by followed this blog https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/b/weblog/archive/2015/12/15/getting-started-with-dxa-java

Could anyone share some links or documents for development?

I plan to use DXA Java version 1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For development you can refer the [official documentation link](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v3/GUID-2DEBAC0B-C053-4221-B7B9-9966D03A25B1#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-41A36F76-1154-4D8A-B2C9-D62F9829A7F2.xml&docid=GUID-41A36F76-1154-4D8A-B2C9-D62F9829A7F2&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-41A36F76-1154-4D8A-B2C9-D62F9829A7F2)